# Alternative to upload files to S3 from Powershell without using AWS SDK for .NET?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

I need to upload files (for a total of 100GB with several files of 10GB) from a PowerShell script to S3:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/Index.html (Amazon Simple Storage Service)

I have used AWS SDK for .NET and works perfectly for small number of files. I just create the bucket in previous code and try to upload all the files with Write-S3Object

```
Write-S3Object -Region $S3_Region -AccessKey $S3_AccessKey -SecretKey $S3_SecretKey -ServerSideEncryption "AES256" -Folder $sourceFolder -BucketName $S3_Bucket -Recurse -KeyPrefix "/"
```

But I have several problems with stability. It fails very often with two types of errors. (There are 4683 files to upload)

- Suddenly with no error it finishes just uploading part of the files

> Uploaded 2664 object(s) to bucket 'bucket.test' from
>   'R:\temp\files' with keyprefix '/'

- It fails with exception:

> Uploaded 35 object(s) to bucket 'bucket.test' from
>   'R:\temp\files' with keyprefix '/'
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The specified upload does not exist.
>   The upload ID may be invalid, or the upload may have been aborted or
>   completed. ---> Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception: The specified upload does
>   not exist. The upload ID may be invalid, or the upload may have been
>   aborted or completed. --->
>   Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: The remote server
>   returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

So my questions are:

- Am I doing something wrong?
- Is there any workaround or fix for my problem?
- Is there any other way to upload without using AWS SDK for .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using Write-S3Object I am using [S3 TransferUtility](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility.htm) object that has the capability to upload large files using multipart upload.

I have been using the below powershell script to upload files to S3.

```
function UploadToAmazonUsingSDK()
{
    param([string] $sourceLocation, [string] $bucketName, [string] $versionNumber)    

    Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS SDK for .NET\bin\Net45\AWSSDK.dll"

    $AccessKey= "your aws accesskey"
    $SecretKey ="your secret key"

    $s3Config=New-Object Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config
    $s3Config.UseHttp = $false
    $s3Config.ServiceURL = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
    $s3Config.BufferSize = 1024 * 32

    $client=[Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($AccessKey,$SecretKey,$s3Config)

    $transferUtility = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility($client)   

    $files = Get-ChildItem $sourceLocation

    foreach ($fileName in $files) {        
        $amazonKey = $versionNumber + '/' + $fileName        
        Write-Host $amazonKey
        Write-Host $fileName 
        Write-Host $fileName.FullName

        $transferUtilRequest = New-Object -TypeName Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtilityUploadRequest
        $transferUtilRequest.BucketName = $bucketName
        $transferUtilRequest.FilePath = $fileName.FullName
        $transferUtilRequest.Key = $amazonKey
        $transferUtilRequest.AutoCloseStream = $true
        $transferUtility.Upload($transferUtilRequest)
    }    
}
```

Comment: it works as a charm. The function is not exactly what I need but is ok as TransferUtility has a method for directories. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are Golang fan you can try out https://github.com/minio/mc. We also have a precompiled binary for Windows on 64bit which can be used with powershell, command prompt etc.

https://dl.minio.io:9000/updates/2015/Sept/windows-amd64/mc.exe

To add your S3 credentials simply do

```
C:\> mc.exe config host add s3.amazonaws.com BKIKJAA5BMMU2RHO6IBB V7f1CwQqAcwo80UEIJEjc5gVQUSSx5ohQ9GSrr12
```

`mc.exe` implements a nice progress bar, colored console output, multipart uploads, session management etc.

We will be making a new release upcoming week as well which will have 32bit and 64bit Windows both supported.